How to print the line number of the caller function from a template function?
I am implementing a log function which logs along with line number of the code. The snippet of the code as follows:
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

char m_buffer[500];

template<typename... Args>
void format_buffer(int line, const char* logData, Args... args)
{
    snprintf(m_buffer, 500, logData, line, args...);
    cout << m_buffer << endl;
}

template<int line = __builtin_LINE(), typename... Args>
void log_error(const char* logData, Args... args)
{
    format_buffer(line, logData, args...);
}

int main()
{
    float f1 = 12.35f;
    log_error("Line %d: Sample error, signal value is %f",f1);
    return 0;
}

Here, the output is as follows:
Line 15: Sample error, signal value is 12.350000

The line number of the template function prints here but not the log statement.
I tried using the __LINE__ macro as shown below:
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

char m_buffer[500];

template<typename... Args>
void format_buffer(int line, const char* logData, Args... args)
{
    snprintf(m_buffer, 500, logData, line, args...);
    cout << m_buffer << endl;
}

template<typename... Args>
void log_error(int line, const char* logData, Args... args)
{
    format_buffer(line, logData, args...);
}

int main()
{
    float f1 = 12.35f;
    log_error(__LINE__, "Line %d: Sample error, signal value is %f",f1);
    return 0;
}

The output is:
Line 24: Sample error, signal value is 12.350000

The line number prints as the log Statement.
My concern is I don't want the user to use the __LINE__ macro in every log statement, instead I want to take the line number from the API. In fact, I don't want my function to use a format specifier for line like below.
log_error("Line %d: Sample error, signal value is %f",f1);

I want the user to use as below:
log_error("Sample error, signal value is %f",f1);

Which prints the line number automatically.
Is it possible to get the line number of the log statement without the user specifying the macro?
Note: I am using a C++14 compiler.

Can you use boost?

@TedLyngmo, I can use boost but how?

I added links to both boost and a wiki about the standard library version of source_location to an answer that lets ju skip using __LINE__ every time you want to log something

Side note, I think logging with line numbers is kind of pointless (you log too much detail) and it feels like you want to do it for debugging reasons. Debugging is better handled by writing unit tests and debugging them. Adding logging slows down your code and can even introduce bugs of its own, specially with a global log buffer like you have (al you need is one more thread in your code and logging will be a problem)

For a quick fix, you could use a macro, and also, skip having the user provide "Line %d: " since that's a required part of the format string. Add that part in your log_error function instead.
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>

thread_local char m_buffer[512]; // thread local to be usable from multiple threads

template <std::size_t N, class... Args>
void log_error(int line, const char (&logData)[N], Args... args) {
    static_assert(N < sizeof(m_buffer) / 8, "suspiciously long format string");

    auto linelen = std::snprintf(m_buffer, sizeof m_buffer, "Line %d: ", line);

    if (std::snprintf(m_buffer + linelen, sizeof m_buffer - linelen,
                      logData, line, args...) > 0)
    {
        std::cout << m_buffer << std::endl;
    }
}

#define LOG_ERROR(...) log_error(__LINE__, __VA_ARGS__)

int main() {
    float f1 = 12.35f;
    LOG_ERROR("Sample error, signal value is %f", f1);
}

Demo
Otherwise, take a look at boost::source_location which is included in the standard library as std::source_location since C++20.

Why is the __LINE__ value being passed in as a template argument instead of a function argument?

@RemyLebeau I figured it didn't matter which one I chose since there often be one instantiation per given set of function parameters anyway and if that's the case,  having it as a constant is always nice, but I didn't really give that part much thought. I made it a regular function argument now instead.
